# Is there a Texstudio keyboard shortcut for moving to new paragraph (up and down)?

Tags: texstudio, keyboard, shortcut

I'm on a Mac and wondering if there is a Texstudio keyboard shortcut that can move the cursor up/down to a new paragraph, starting at the beginning of the paragraph. Supposedly option + up/down arrow is supposed to work on a mac to accomplish this, but it doesn't really work in Texstudio (it moves to the end of the line, then to the end of the paragraph, then to the blank space, then finally to the beginning of the next paragraph).

I'm wondering if a shortcut can be added in Texstudio itself, or through BetterTouchTool, or through the Mac itself that can accomplish this. It will make editing documents much more convenient without having to click around with the mouse.